# My Pet Bag project: How to make these functions work?

Tags: java

Novice java coder here, expert java drinker. I've been working on an assignment for my class all day where I have to write a java class known as "Pet" for a fictional program called Pet BAG(Boarding and grooming) for my fictional employer Global Rain. Anyway, I have alot of said  code written, and am continuing to work on it dilligently however I have hit a roadblock. When I try the instant feed back tool I get "getDogSpaces()" or "getCatSpaces()" functions seem to be missing. Can anyone help me understand why I get this error so I can fix it and move on? I am stunped. My code is posted below.

```
public class Pet {

//Atrributes

private String petType;
private String petName;
private int petAge;
private int dogSpaces;
private int catSpaces;
private int daysStay;
private double amountDue;

public Pet (String petType, String petName, int petAge, int daysStay) {
    setPetType(petType);
    setPetName(petName);
    setPetAge(petAge);
    setDogSpace(30);
    setCatSpace(12);
    setDaysStay(daysStay);
    
}

//Accessors

public String getPetType() {
    return petType;
}

public String getPetName() {
    return petName;
}

public int getPetAge() {
    return petAge;
}

public void setPetAge(int setPetAge) {
    this.petAge = petAge;
}

public int getDogSpace() {
    return dogSpace;
}

public void setDogSpace(int dogSpace) {
    this.dogSpace = dogSpace;
}

public int getCatSpace() {
    return catSpace;
}

public void setCatSpace(int catSpace) {
    this.catSpace = catSpace;
}

public int getDaysStay() {
    return daysStay;
}

public void setDaysStay(int daysStay) {
    this.daysStay = daysStay;
}

public double getAmountDue() {
    return amountDue;
}

public void setAmountDue(double amountDue) {
    this.amountDue = amountDue;
}

}
```

I know my code block seems strange, but I did my best to line it up properly. Could anyone assist me?

Thank you,

Joseph

Comment: getDogSpaces() is not the same as getDogSpace(). Same for the cat method. If you are calling one but implemented the other, Java will complain that you're calling methods that don't exist.